# CruiseControl.NET notification when someone stops a build

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net

Is there a setting in CruiseControl.NET that can be configured to send out notifications if someone stops a build? We've had cases where a user stopped the build, and forgot about it, and didn't start it up again. Ideally, others on the team would have been notified that the build was stopped manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of a setting that will send an email notification.  The docs don't seem to indicate so at any rate.  The email notificationTypes include the following (and cancel is absent).

- Always
- Change
- Failed
- Success
- Fixed
- Exception

But if you use the cctray.exe program, which comes with CruiseControl.NET, it will tell you when a build is cancelled.

You should be able to download and install cctray right from your CCNet dashboard (Screenshot below)

[image]